# DataBinding multiple instances of members of a class to specific labels

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

[image][image]I have a class that has a private member of another class, and which that class is an ObserveableCollection of another class.. and this is the class I need info from, that has private members that I want to databind.

```
private readonly NflGameCollection _games;
....

class NflGameCollection : ObservableCollectionEx<NflGameStatus>
    {...

class NflGameStatus : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    //***these are the members i want databound***
    private readonly string _homeTri;
    private readonly string _awayTri;
    private string _homeScore;
    private string _awayScore;
```

so multiple instances of this NflGameStatus will pop up everytime it detects a game... which the only way i know how to access it is by doing this:

```
_controller = new DtvGsisDataParser.AppController();
    foreach (var item in _controller.Games)
            {
                string hometri = item.HomeTri;
                string awaytri = item.AwayTri;
        ... etc etc
            }
```

how can i get it so that if a hometri and awaytri are equal to what i'm looking for... i can get the other instances of that class?  for example

```
if item.HomeTri==what i want && item.AwayTri==what i want
        then bind item._homeScore to a certain label
        then bind item.awayAScore to a certain label.
```

i know what i'm asking for is kinda complex.. but i'm kinda desperate here and would appreciate any help.  this databinding is very new to me and i'm having trouble grasping it.  is this even possible?  the more i research the more i dont think so.. but i'm hoping i'm not.  thanks for any help

Comment: You want to bind the values to the same labels each time?  Or do you want to bind to different labels depending on some logic?

Comment: i'd like to bind dynamically created labels dependent on the homeTri and awayTri of that class.  but there will be multiple instances of homeTri's and awayTri's which i only know how to access through a foreach statement... let me know if that answered your question.  if i can't figure this out.. i guess i'll have to make a timer to update the labels every 1 second or something.  would rather learn how to do this the proper way though =T

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you want to show up in your UI.  Could you elaborate about what the visual result will be?

Comment: sure let me take a screen shot

Comment: so the first pic is how it looks in my xaml... then when i run it (2nd pic) is how it looks right when it runs as it reads all the info from a SQL database on load (everything on the TabControl are dynamically created).  now the scores and times for each game.. i need to be updating to the "real time" game clock and score which comes from a different program that updates in real time to each appropriate tab according to the homeTri and awayTri.  does that make sense a little more?  let me know if it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to bind your tab control to a collection of ViewModels, one for each game:

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding GameModels}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding GameTitle}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding GameContent}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

The ViewModel could look like:

```
public class NflGame : ViewModelBase
{
    public String GameTitle;
    public NflGameContent GameContent;
}
```

And each `NflGameContent` could look like:

```
public class NflGameContent : ViewModelBase
{
    private Thread _worker;

    public NflGameContent(int gameID){
        _worker = new Thread(() => UpdateScores(gameID));
        _worker.Start();
    }

    private UpdateScores(gameID){
       var appController = new DtvGsisDataParser.AppController(); //Or whatever -- you get the idea
       HomeScoreText = appController.GetHomeScore(gameID);
       AwayScoreText = appController.GetAwayScore(gameID);
       OnPropertyChanged("HomeScoreText");
       OnPropertyChanged("AwayScoreText");
    }

    public String HomeScoreText;
    public String AwayScoreText;
}
```

Then of course your XAML would be bound to the NflGameContent and receive updates OnPropertyChanged:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HomeScoreText}">
```

Comment: very interesting.  thanks you very much for this.. i'm currently looking how to implement this according to what you wrote.  tyvm

Comment: for this part right here: "<TextBlock Text="{Binding HomeScoreText}">".. since i'm creating the labels dynamically (ex: team1ScoreLabel = new Label(); _grid.Children.Add(team1ScoreLabel);)... how could i do the equivalent of that WPF you pasted in that line as C#?  i think i understand how to do it except that one part

Comment: @user1189352 How come you're dynamically adding children?

Comment: that's just how i coded it originally.... and i have a deadline on this unfortunately (boss doesn't care how i do it, just get it done type of thing) and it would take too much time to learn WPF/Databinding the proper way and to re-do my code.. so i unfortunately have to work with what i have =T

Comment: whoops i didn't understand, i meant to say i dynamically created everything because it only creates the labels and objects according to how to a SQL database i'm reading

Comment: @user1189352 Ok. So it creates all the XAML for you?  What's some of the XAML look like?

Comment: i did it all in C# unfortunately.. this is why this is so difficult unfortunately =[  oh well think i give up.. i dont understand enough of this databinding and WPF stuff to make this work.  i appreciate all your help though

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is you set the DataContext of the control to the game you wish to display:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedGame}">
    <Label Content="{Binding HomeScoreText}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding AwayScoreText}" />
</StackPanel>
```

So first of all you would need to expose the `HomeScoreText` and `AwayScoreText` as public properties on the `NflGameStatus` class like this:

```
class NflGameStatus
{
    private readonly string _homeTri;
    private readonly string _awayTri;
    private string _homeScore;
    private string _awayScore;

    public String HomeScoreText
    {
        get
        {
            return _homeScore;
        }
    }
    public String AwayScoreText
    {
        get
        {
            return _awayScore;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will need to expose a public property on your ViewModel like this:

```
private NflGameStatus _selectedGame;
public NflGameStatus SelectedGame
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedGame;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedGame = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedGame");
    }
}
```

Now when you set the SelectedGame property it will automatically update those fields. So just do a check:

```
if item.HomeTri==what i want && item.AwayTri==what i want
    SelectedGame = item;
```

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: hm i think i get the idea of what i need to do.. thank you so much.. will come back to this.  i'll probably have a question or two, so please check back -.-